# Background image doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background-image, sections

```
.imagem-cortada {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("imagens/Vector 9.png");
}
```

The HTML:

```
<section class="imagem-cortada conteudo-principal"><!--inicio sobre nos-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="verde h2 fonte-bold">
            Sobre nós               
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--fim sobre nos-->
```

but the image does not appear.

Comment: Change the name of the file don't but spaces in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your html and CSS appears correct. below I showed it working with a different image. This leads me to believe that your route to your image is incorrect. (you should probably have a "/" at the beginning of it.

```css
.imagem-cortada {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png");
}
```

```html
<section class="imagem-cortada conteudo-principal"><!--inicio sobre nos-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="verde h2 fonte-bold">
            Sobre nós               
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```